# Wordpress Image Uploader As Thumbnail

Tags: wordpress

**How can I convert the uploaded image to a 125x166px thumbnail?**

```
// jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

// This will enqueue the Media Uploader script
wp_enqueue_media();

var image = wp.media({
     title: 'Upload Image',
     multiple: false
    }).open()
      .on('select', function (e) {
        // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
        var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
        // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
        // Output to the console uploaded_image
        console.log(uploaded_image);
        var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `wp_get_image_editor` function.

Examples of how to use is available at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor

But this is using PHP

Comment: Real nice and simple.  Thanks.